# point labels in R scatter plot

Tags: r, plot

I have the following toy data

```
Xeafield (1999) (PER) ,1,0.5745375408
Lancelot et al. (1989),0.9394939494,0.4733405876
LemLM Xeafield (1997) (TER) ,0.6265126513,0.2959738847
Almore and Flemin (2001) (KER),0.4218921892,0.5745375408
Malek et al. (2006) (HER) ,0.4125412541,1
Charles and Osborne (2003),0.0308030803,0.1414581066
```

And trying a simple 2D plot in R with points labeled using the 1st column.

```
pdf('data.pdf', width = 7, height = 8)

d1 <- read.csv("data.csv", header=F, dec=".",sep = ",")
plot(as.matrix(d1[,2]), as.matrix(d1[,3]), col= "blue", pch = 19, cex = 1, lty = "solid", lwd = 2, ylim=c(0,1), xaxt = "n",yaxt = "n")

text(as.matrix(d1[,2]), as.matrix(d1[,3]), labels=as.matrix(d1[,1]), cex= 0.7, pos=3)

x_axis_range <- c(0,1) 
x_axis_labels <- c("Small","Large")
axis(1,at = x_axis_range, labels = x_axis_labels)

y_axis_range <- c(0,1) 
y_axis_labels <- c("Slow","Fast")
axis(2,at = y_axis_range, labels = y_axis_labels)
title(xlab="Memory", ylab="Speed",cex.lab=1)
dev.off()
```

But the plot doesn't come out right. A few issues I have: the axis label are messed up (it shows as.matrix ..., instead of the label I specified), and the margin of the plot is to small that node labels are cutoff. I am new to using R and plot, appreciate your help.

[image]

Comment: Try to add xlabel and ylabel as use plot().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution for your problem is to define axis labels and axis ranges in the `plot` function.

```
d1 <- structure(list(V1 = structure(c(6L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 5L, 2L), .Label = c("Almore and Flemin (2001) (KER)", 
"Charles and Osborne (2003)", "Lancelot et al. (1989)", "LemLM Xeafield (1997) (TER) ", 
"Malek et al. (2006) (HER) ", "Xeafield (1999) (PER) "), class = "factor"), 
    V2 = c(1, 0.9394939494, 0.6265126513, 0.4218921892, 0.4125412541, 
    0.0308030803), V3 = c(0.5745375408, 0.4733405876, 0.2959738847, 
    0.5745375408, 1, 0.1414581066)), .Names = c("V1", "V2", "V3"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))

# Use xlab and ylab for axis labels and
# and xlim and ylim for setting axis ranges
plot(as.matrix(d1[,2]), as.matrix(d1[,3]), col= "blue", pch = 19, 
    cex = 1, lty = "solid", lwd = 2, ylim=c(-0.1,1.1), xaxt = "n",yaxt = "n",
    xlab="Memory", ylab="Speed",cex.lab=1, xlim=c(-0.1,1.1))

text(as.matrix(d1[,2]), as.matrix(d1[,3]), 
     labels=as.matrix(d1[,1]), cex= 0.7, pos=3)

x_axis_range <- c(0,1) 
x_axis_labels <- c("Small","Large")
axis(1,at = x_axis_range, labels = x_axis_labels)

y_axis_range <- c(0,1) 
y_axis_labels <- c("Slow","Fast")
axis(2,at = y_axis_range, labels = y_axis_labels)
```

[image]